# docker stack deploy depends_on

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

Given compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  whoami1:
    image: containous/whoami
    depends_on:
      - whoami2
  whoami2:
    image: containous/whoami
```

when deployed to docker swarm `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml test`
services `whoami1` and `whoami2` seem to start in random order and ignore `depends_on` condition.

```
 docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml test
Creating network test_default
Creating service test_whoami1
Creating service test_whoami2
```

Does docker swarm support service startup sequencing via dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

No, at least not built in.

Even with depends_on the `whoami2` may not yet be ready to interact with `whoami1` because it may need time to boot itself:

> However, for startup Compose does not wait until a container is “ready” (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running. There’s a good reason for this.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

They hint at two possibilites to check if `whoami2` is ready.

> Use a tool such as wait-for-it, dockerize, or sh-compatible wait-for. These are small wrapper scripts which you can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and port until it’s accepting TCP connections.

And depends_on is indeed ignored for docker swarm:

> There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:
>
> - (...)
> - The depends_on option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on